# Possible for Paypal to get the certificate id on localhost?

Tags: php, paypal, localhost, paypal-sandbox

I am new to button encryption with Paypal. I followed the tutorial on http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php, but I'm working on localhost. My application says that it is "unable to decrypt the certificate id". Is it possible for Paypal to get the certificate id on localhost?

Comment: I cannot remember how I did it on localhost it was about 4 years ago. But I am sure that I did it on my XAMPP install. You can definatly post to the PayPal server, you just wont get a response on your local machine

Comment: can you know hoe to get response on local machine from paypal

Comment: It's not possible as far as I know, unless you modify your router settings. Better to test on a live server

Comment: r u sure brother we should change in router

Comment: I wouldn't bother - I would use an external server. One that sits behind a domain such as www.example.com. For the sake of a bit of testing it would be far better setting it up on a live server! The time it will take you to set up on a local server will outweigh the benefits!

Comment: can you provide me any document related to setting up in live server.if u it will will help full for me

Comment: Checkout the paypal documentation: https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_encryptedwebpayments